# Reading int(NSCFNumber) from array of dictionary

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary, alamofire

I am using Alamofire with SwiftyJSON. I can succesfully read from API as in below:

```
Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts").responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
let swiftyJsonVar = JSON(responseData.result.value!)

if let resData = swiftyJsonVar.arrayObject {
self.arrRes = resData as! [[String:AnyObject]]
}
if self.arrRes.count > 0 {
self.results_tableView.reloadData()
}
} }
```

But i can't get the values **dict["id"]** and **dict["userId"]** from dictionary to display in the cell.

```
var dict = arrRes[indexPath.row]
cell.label_body.text = dict["body"] as? String
cell.label_title.text = dict["title"] as? String
cell.label_id.text = dict["id"] as? String **//prints (nil)**
cell.label_userId.text = dict["userId"] as? String **//prints (nil)**
```

[image]

And this is the declarition of my Array of Dictionary at the top:

```
var arrRes = [[String:AnyObject]]() //Array of dictionary
```

Thank you very much for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this

```
if let userId = dict["userId"] {
   cell.label_userId.text = "\(userId)"
}
```

Hope this will fix your problem

Answer (score 1):

This is the sample dictionary , we get from server.Here the the id is an id and userid are integers.So instead of type casting to string ,type cast to Int or NSNumber.

```
{
"userId": 1,
"id": 2,
"title": "qui est esse",
"body": "est rerum tempore vitae\nsequi sint nihil reprehenderit dolor beatae ea dolores neque\nfugiat blanditiis voluptate porro vel nihil molestiae ut reiciendis\nqui aperiam non debitis possimus qui neque nisi nulla"
```

}

```
cell.label_id.text = String(dict["id"] as? Int ?? 0)
cell.label_userId.text = Stringdict["userId"] as? Int ?? 0)
```

OR

```
cell.label_id.text = String(dict["id"] as? NSNumber ?? 0)
cell.label_userId.text = String(dict["userId"] as? NSNumber ?? 0)
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understood your json response properly, you can get it as below:

```
   if let id = dict["id"] {
      cell.label_id.text = "\(id)"
   }
   if let userID = dict["userId"] {
      cell.label_userId.text = "\(userID)"
   }
```

Comment: Thank you very much 'Santosh'. Your answer is true as Kuntal's but i accepted his as i saw it before.